# Disable pingbacks and trackbacks in blog posts

Tags: pingbacks

Just created a new self-hosted WordPress blog, and among the very first things, I "unchecked" the `Allow link notifications from other blogs (pingbacks and trackbacks)` option under **Settings** > **Discussion**.

I was fixing a few things for the to-be-launched-soon blog, when I noticed a pingback on the default **"Hello world!"** post on my blog.

But I've already disabled pingbacks/trackbacks, so why exactly is this happening? What could be wrong?

Comment: This is not a duplicate. I actually did search before posting this Q/A -- and found **no exact duplicate**. And I wouldn't post this if it was so trivial to me until I realized...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is, the default post has both comments and pingbacks/trackbacks enabled by default. And post or page level settings override the site-wide settings.

So, for ONLY the **"Hello world!"** post (if you are not deleting it), you'll have to specifically uncheck `Allow trackbacks and pingbacks on this page.` option which is available when you check the **Discussion** option under **Screen Options** menu:

[image: ping/track]